# Fold Coverage of sequence read?

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-analysis

What does it mean when N-Fold coverage of read of sequence? Details will be much appreciated if a link provider with brief explanation.

Comment: What you're asking is a little unclear to me...I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but typically, the fold coverage of a read represents the number of times that particular read was sequenced in a given run.

Answer (score 3):

Fold coverage is often derived with respect to a genomic locus, not a read. In sequencing experiments, fold coverage of a genomic loci (coordinate along a reference assembly) will be the number of aligned reads that overlap the position.

Comment: It could also be the average coverage of a genome based on number of reads, read length and expected genome size.

Comment: Thank you for the additional detail. Absolutely, on a genome level the fold coverage is computed as: number of reads * read length / genome size, and genome size here be either the true genome size or the size of the fraction of genome that is captured for sequencing.

Answer (score 0):

N-fold coverage usually refer to the average number of reads spanning across a particular region of interest. For example, if you are interested in a gene and would like to know how confident your data is, you may look for the coverage.

There is no absolute definition on how N-fold coverage is calculated. The most common method is to get the arithmetic average per base.